# Matrix inversion for matrix with large values in python

Tags: python, matrix-inverse

I'm doing matrix inversion in python, and I found it very weird that the result differs by the data scale.

In the code below, it is expected that A_inv/B_inv = B/A. However, it shows that the difference between A_inv/B_inv and B/A becomes larger and larger depend on the data scale... Is this because Python cannot compute matrix inverse precisely for matrix with large values?

Also, I checked the condition number for B, which is a constant ~3.016 no matter the scale is.

Thanks!!!

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

D = 30
N = 300

np.random.seed(10)
original_data = np.random.sample([D, N])
A = np.cov(original_data)
A_inv = np.linalg.inv(A)


B_cond = []
diff = []

for k in xrange(1,10):
    B = A * np.power(10,k)
    B_cond.append(np.linalg.cond(B))
    B_inv = np.linalg.inv(B)

    ### Two measurements of difference are used

    diff.append(np.log(np.linalg.norm(A_inv/B_inv - B/A)))
    #diff.append(np.max(np.abs(A_inv/B_inv - B/A)))



# print B_cond

plt.figure()
plt.plot(xrange(1,10), diff)
plt.xlabel('data(B) / data(A)')
plt.ylabel('log(||A_inv/B_inv - B/A||)')
plt.savefig('Inversion for large matrix')
```

Answer (score 1):

I may be wrong, but I think it comes from number representation in machine.
When you are dealing with great numbers, your inverse matrix is going to have very little number in magnitude (close to zero). And clsoe to zero, the representation of the floating number is not precise enough, I guess...
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic

Comment: Yeah I don't know how python computes the inverse, but the `B` matrix apparently have determinant = `inf` after some rounds. Not sure if this could cause problems...

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason that you should expect `np.linalg.norm(A_inv/B_inv - B/A)` to be equal to anything special.  Instead, you can check the quality of the inverse calculation by multiplying the original matrix by its inverse and checking the determinant, `np.linalg.det(A.dot(A_inv))`, which should be equal to 1.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I used `C=np.dot(B_inv, B)`, it has `1.000000` on the diagonal, but values in non-diagonal cells are on the order of `1e-17` . How to test if `C` is a good identity matrix? Thanks!

Comment: I'm expecting `np.linalg.norm(A_inv/B_inv - B/A) = 0`, if the magnitudes match for the original matrix and for the inversed ones